# Scroll div with regard to another div on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which gets fixed on top of the page as the page scrolls up to it's height. This div has a drop-down which acts as tags for the divs below.

As and when a div name is selected from this drop down, that div should scroll up to the place where the fixed div is ending. Currently, it is scrolling to the top of page.

You can see the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/eranjali08/b7W95/

```
function ScrollToElement(element) {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + element).position().top
    }, 'slow');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the "fixToTop" class is added, the element's height is being removed from the document. If the scroll started before it was added, the scroll ends in the wrong place.

This can be avoided by adding the original height to an element when the class is added and setting it back to 0 when the class is removed.

```
function topContainer_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ($('#topContainer-anchor').offset()) {
        var div_top = $('#topContainer-anchor').offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top) {
            $('#topContainerSpace').height($('#topContainer').height());
            $('#topContainer').addClass('fixToTop');
        } else {
            $('#topContainer').removeClass('fixToTop');
            $('#topContainerSpace').height(0);
        }
    } else {
        $('#topContainer').removeClass('fixToTop');
        $('#topContainerSpace').height(0);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="topContainerSpace"></div>
<div id="topContainer">
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the fixed div height from the top position like this:

```
    function ScrollToElement(element) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + element).position().top - $('#topContainer').height()
        }, 'slow');
    }
```

You can also add a small padding:

```
    function ScrollToElement(element) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + element).position().top - $('#topContainer').height() - 5
        }, 'slow');
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jA4DS/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I tried doing this and it doesn't work. Even in your fiddle, try to select B and it the section goes below the fixed div :(